# import a CSV file with JSONB into postgresql 14

Tags: postgresql, copy, parquet, loaddata

I am looking to load this two rows below from a csv file with second value being JSONB [column name: details].

```
1,"{""fields0"": [""is_enabled""], ""t_id"": ""Lcum"", ""fields1"": [""is_enabled""], ""m_id"": ""xdrd""}",completed,2020-07-22 15:24:31.083853+00,2020-07-22 15:24:31.2443+00
2,"{""fields0"": [""is_enabled""], ""t_id"": ""Lcum"", ""fields1"": [""is_enabled""], ""m_id"": ""xdrd""}",completed,2020-07-22 15:25:15.16227+00,2020-07-22 15:25:15.317736+00
```

```
\copy task (id,details,status,time_started,time_completed) FROM '0000-2893fb23.parquet.csv' csv header escape E'\n' quote '"';
```

the error i receive

"ERROR:  extra data after last expected column"

can someone advise what i am doing wrong

Comment: Why `escape E'\n'`?  What do you think that achieves?

Comment: my understanding is this will pick the second line after the first one. please let me know if its otherwise

Comment: No, "header" tells it to skip the first row. (which is unclear on why you want to do that, given your example data and your stated intentions).  Setting the escape to newline means that instead of doubling `"` to include them as literals, you instead have to prepend them with newlines.  It is hard to think of a good reason to ever do this.  Anyway, when I run your example command with your example data, I go get an error but it is not the one you indicate.  If your example is not accurate, we can't know what is really going on.

Answer (score 0):

According to error which you are encountering there may be an issue with the data format in your CSV file, or it may not be corresponding to the table which you created, so here are few things which you should check;

Make sure your CSV file doesn't contain any extra columns or information that isn't specified in the "task" table. Your CSV should have the same number of columns as the structure of the table, according to PostgreSQL.

Make sure your CSV file doesn't have any extra delimiters or stray commas that might be causing PostgreSQL to interpret the data erroneously.

Verify that the CSV file ("0000-2893fb23.parquet.csv") you are attempting to import is in fact in the proper format and does not contain any unusual characters or formatting issues.

Comment: the json column "value" have lot of comma's which the copy command thinks they are individual columns. I will try to use different delimiter and test. The files does not have any extra columns which have been verified.